# Реализация множественного владения

Tags: rust

Нужно переделать [пример из документации](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/), что бы Owner имел имел функцию make_gadget, а Gadget - change_owner

Пример

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Owner {
    name: String,
    gadgets: RefCell<Vec<Rc<Gadget>>>,
}

impl Owner {
    fn make_gadget(&mut self, id: i32) -> Rc<Gadget> {
        let gadget = Rc::new(Gadget{id: id, owner: /* how to reference there to self? */});
        self.gadgets.into_inner().push(gadget.clone());
        gadget
    }
}

struct Gadget {
    id: i32,
    owner: Rc<Owner>,
}

fn main() {
    let gadget_owner : Rc<Owner> = Rc::new(
            Owner {
                name: "Gadget Man".to_string(),
                gadgets: RefCell::new(Vec::new()),
            }
        );

    let gadget1 = gadget_owner.make_gadget(1);
    let gadget2 = gadget_owner.make_gadget(2);

}
```

Comment: В вопросе отсутствует описание проблемы и предпринятых шагов.

Comment: Не знал, с чего даже начать, исправил.

Comment: Боюсь в данном варианте как он есть работать не будет в принципе, так как Rc — владеющий указатель, а в методе make_gadget есть только ссылка на self. Ну и into_inner тоже так не взлетит, нужно borrow_mut, потому что опять же будет can not move out of borrowed context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При преобразовании объекта с типом `Owner` в `Rc<Owner>` происходит передача владения. Т.е. невозможно получить из одного `Owner` больше одного `Rc<Owner>`.

Чтобы получить несколько `Rc`-указателей на один объект нужно клонировать сами указатели `Rc<Owner>`.

Функция `make_gadget` должна в качестве входного параметра получать не `&Owner`, а `&Rc<Owner>`. Можно сделать для нее типаж (trait) и реализовать его для `Rc<Owner>`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Owner {
    name: String,
    gadgets: RefCell<Vec<Weak<Gadget>>>,//must be Weak instead Rc to avoid cyclic reference
}

trait Maker{
    fn make_gadget(&self, id: i32) -> Rc<Gadget>;
}

impl Maker for Rc<Owner> {
    fn make_gadget(&self, id: i32) -> Rc<Gadget> {
        let gadget = Rc::new(Gadget{id: id, owner: self.clone()});
        self.gadgets.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(&gadget));
        gadget
    }
}

struct Gadget {
    id: i32,
    owner: Rc<Owner>,
}

fn main() {
    let gadget_owner : Rc<Owner> = Rc::new(
            Owner {
                name: "Gadget Man".to_string(),
                gadgets: RefCell::new(Vec::new()),
            }
        );

    let gadget1 = gadget_owner.make_gadget(1);
    let gadget2 = gadget_owner.make_gadget(2);
}
```

В массиве `Owner::gadgets` нужно использовать указатель `Weak` вместо `Rc` иначе образуются циклические ссылки

Comment: Воу, и тут все прояснилось, гениально, спасибо!